# Spectral radius of an element in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

The
 following is an proposition of Takesaki's Operator Theory:

For any element $x$ of a Banach algebra ${\cal A}$, we have 
$$||x||_{sp}=\lim_{n\to \infty}||x^n||^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Proof:

[image]

My question: Why does he use bounded linear functionals of ${\cal A}$ to
 show that the sequence $\{\frac{x^n}{\lambda^{n+1}}\}$ is bounded? I 
think because the power series $f(\lambda)=(\lambda - 
x)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n} {\lambda^{n+1}}$ convergences, then 
$\frac{x^n}{\lambda^{n+1}}\to 0 $ and therefore this sequence is 
bounded. Am I right? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the convergence of the series only gives rise to an upper bound on the spectral radius. (Werner actually splits this into three or four theorems - if you read that part on the spectrum of bounded operators you will understand why ;)...)

Comment: @Freeze_S :I can not understand your mean. Please explain more, also please give me a reference to read those theorems.

Comment: No problem. So you start with the C. Neumann series. That tells you that any lambda with mod strictly bigger than the let me call it Hadamard radius belongs to the resolvent set. For lambdas strictly smaller than the Hadamard radius the series certainly diverges; however, that does not prove yet that there's another representation for the inverse and that is the tricky point. You remember maybe from complex analysis that an analytic function can be expanded in a power series at a point that converges up to the biggest ball that first hits a singularity, after that the power series certainly...

Comment: ... diverges everywhere(!) outside. However if you just slip around the singularity you can find a new power series around a new point so the old representating power series is just not more valid anymore but still there is a representation by a power series it's just another one. And that is what makes the proof "so" difficult that you just cannot conclude that by the divergence of that specific power series that it cannot belong to the resolvent set anymore there just might be another expression for the resolvent.

Comment: Ah by the way see section Spectrum of a bounded operator of Werner's Funktionalanalysis (German version)

Comment: See the point is that one doesn't know a priori that $f(\lambda)=(\lambda-x)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{\lambda^{n+1}}$ converges even for $|\lambda|\geq\|x\|_{sp}$.

Comment: @Freeze_S : That's a straightforward verification. Multiply the the truncated series on the left (or the right) by $(\lambda 1-x)$ and see what you get. This is not tough at all, and I mentioned that in my post. If that series converges, it must converge to the desired thing; nothing tough there.

Comment: @T.A.E.: I know that!!!!! That is simply telescoping sum but still that argument doesn't work if convergence is not guaranteed as $|\lambda|>r_\sigma(A)$ does not imply $|\lambda|>r_H(A)$ a priori.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Extended discussion...*
*(Find a draft of the solution below!)*

**Query**

T.A.E. nicely showed Hadamard's criterion saying that the series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty A_k$$
converges for $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\|A_k\|^\frac{1}{k}<1$ and certainly diverges for $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\|A_k\|^\frac{1}{k}>1$.

> Now, why does one need bounded linear functionals anyway?

**Explanation**

The point is basically to **establish(!) convergence** of the series:
$$(\lambda-A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{\lambda^{n+1}}\quad(|\lambda|>r_\sigma(A))$$
This is done by drifting into the realm of complex analysis via bounded linear functionals.

> Now, that is why one needs bounded linear functionals anyway!

Moreover, the divergence of the series is **not(!) sufficient** as there might be another expression for the inverse.

As an analog problem consider the real function:
$$f(x):=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$
That one has a power series expansion around zero with radius one - inside it converges and outside it certainly diverges. It is nevertheless analytic on the whole real line just with new power series expansions:
$$f(x)=1-x^2+x^4+\ldots\quad(-1<x<1)$$
$$f(x)=\frac12\mp\frac12(x-1)+\ldots\quad(\pm1-\sqrt{2}<x<\pm1+\sqrt{2})$$
So be careful about drawing conclusions from nonexistent a.k.a. divergent expression!!

---

*Sketchy solution...*

**Problem**

Denote the spectral radius and  the 'Hadamard' radius by:
$$r_\sigma(A):=\sup\|\sigma(A)\|$$
$$r_H(A):=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|A^n\|^\frac{1}{n}$$

The goal is to establish:
$$r_\sigma(A)=r_H(A)$$

**Strategy**

On the one hand for all $|\lambda|>r_H(A)$ the inverse is explicitely given by:
$$(\lambda-A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{\lambda^{n+1}}$$
by Hadamard's formula as mentioned above.

Therefore $r_H(A)\geq r_\sigma(A)$.

...

On the other hand for all $|\lambda|>r_\sigma(A)$ the inverse is analytic so as well for all bounded functionals:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{A}':\quad\varphi\left((\lambda-A)^{-1}\right)\text{ analytic}$$

So from complex analysis the Laurent series must converge:
$$\varphi\left((\lambda-A)^{-1}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\varphi(A^n)}{\lambda^{n+1}}$$

But this means that sequence of summands is bounded for every bounded linear functional separately. By the uniform boundedness theorem this applies without them as well and so:
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\|A^n\|^\frac{1}{n}<|\lambda|$$

Therefore $r_\sigma(A)\geq r_H(A)$.

Especially, again by Hadamard's formula:
$$(\lambda-A)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{\lambda^{n+1}}$$

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula and Hadamard's Theorem allow you to expand in the maximum sized annulus in which the function has a holomorphic extension. This is not only true in the scalar case, but also in the vector using the same expansion of the Cauchy kernel applied to vector functions. If the series you have for $(x-\lambda 1)$ converges absolutely, I noted that it converges to *the* inverse of $(x-\lambda 1)$ (inverses are unique.) Combined with Hadamard, this gives a whole exterior disk where it converges to $(x-\lambda 1)^{-1}$

Comment: You've under-stated the first result. The series converges *absolutely* if $\limsup_{n}\|A_{n}\|^{1/n} < 1$.

Comment: @T.A.E.: That is not important at all and one gains  no insight by it...

Comment: @T.A.E.: and truly the Cauchy formula holds for the Banach space too but neither you nor me used that approach so why bothering about it? If you wanna write an answer using this approach you can do so... I was just about the point that it won't be clear from your answer why bounded linear functionals are needed and since after a long discussion as you didn't add a remark I felt responsible to mention it in an additional answer - point!

Comment: You did not read the OP question correctly at all. He asked about showing the general term of the series to be bounded knowing that it converges. That's exactly what he asked. You're restating incorrecctly. You don't need functionals for that.

Comment: @T.A.E.: The question is "Why does **he** use bounded linear functionals..." that means why does Takesaki and not the OP(!) use it and in fact he does neither assume nor mention convergence of the series in his proof. Moreover, the OP still thinks and not knows that convergence holds a priori.

Comment: You deliberately truncated the question. " Why does he use bounded linear functionals of A to show that the sequence {xnλn+1} is bounded? I think because the power series f(λ)=(λ−x)−1=∑n≥0xnλn+1 convergences, then xnλn+1→0 and therefore this sequence is bounded. " The reasoning is correct if you know that the series converges, which may have been proved in the book at that point; I assumed it had been proved at that point based on the original question. Do you know if the convergence was established by that point? It wouldn't surprise me at all if it had been established already.

Comment: @T.A.E.: if he would have proved it already at that point he most probably wouldn't go by bounded linear functionals at all here - that makes it evident that he didn't. But wait let me check it...

Comment: @T.A.E.: Alright, he did **not** prove nor assume convergence!!! In fact, he introduces the Neumann series first with the weaker bound norm less one, then he defines the spectrum and the spectral radius. Following, he gives a quick proof for the compactness of the spectrum using the norm as estimate and immediately after this he mentions that indeed the spectral radius is not only bound from above by the norm but even by the Hadamard radius and then it comes the scanned part. So no convergence yet for the series outside the disk with spectral radius. Do you agree with me now??!!

Comment: Dear Freeze_S :Thanks for your complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

Takesaki (and most authors) do this because it is technically simpler.
It reduces directly to standard complex analysis.  Otherwise, it would
be necessary to develop a little of the theory of complex analysis with
values in a Banach space and a little integration theory so as to
express Cauchy's formula, or use a special method.  The extension of
complex analysis is very easy by copying standard complex analysis.
The integration theory is only easy.  The simplest way is to define an
integral on step maps from an interval to the Banach space and extend
by continuity (the regulated integral).  The shortest way is to use a weak
integral (the Pettis integral), but that uses exactly the same linear
functional reduction that we are trying to avoid.  The most complete way
is full measure theory going directly to a strong integral (the Bochner integral), (make it more technical to be *the* most complete).

Rudin's books use both methods.  Rudin's books have unusual mixtures
of complex and real and functional analysis, so he is ideally placed
to use the most natural method without having to take a detour to
prove theorems to support it.  However, in *Real and Complex Analysis*,
he only develops standard complex analysis and uses the weak method
for the spectral radius formula. In *Functional Analysis* he doesn't
develop standard complex analysis, but proves in an early chapter
the nontrivial theorem that weakly analytic functions to a Frechet
space are strongly analytic (the converse is obvious).  Before that
he takes 5 pages to develop weak integration for more general spaces.
That Cauchy's formula holds in the weak sense is an easy part of the
proof. Even the weak integration needs much more than the Hahn-Banach
theorem due to its generality.

Then in the proof of the spectral radius formula, Rudin could
reasonably use extended complex analysis after saying that it follows
in the usual way from the integral formula (his integral is only weak,
but estimates made using it are strong).  However, Rudin's style is to
not motivate any of this, and to give full details of minimal proofs.
So instead of proving and/or using the Laurent expansion that follows
from Cauchy's formula, he gives minimal details that repeat a little
of the proof of the Laurent expansion.  Mixing these details makes the
proof unnatural and almost twice as long as the proof in *Real and
Complex Analysis* although the latter has fewer prerequisites.

I don't know of any more direct proofs.  The magic of analyicity seems
to be required to give a radius of convergence.  Strong analyticity is
obvious for the resolvent function.  Standard complex analysis only
obviously implies that the the Laurent expansion holds weakly down to
the radius.  We need to prove that it holds strongly, and it is inelegant
to use the harder (?) theorem that this is automatic.

Comment: I prefer the most direct proofs. Riemann integration works just fine for continuous vector functions. So does Riemann-Stieltjes integration. Then you can establish Cauchy's integral formula by using one application of linear functionals, which gives power series, Laurent series, etc. without further weak arguments; vector convergence is established directly by expanding $1/z-w$ as in the classical case. Of course the one big theorem you don't want to miss is that vector analyticity is implied by weak analyticity; that makes checking very easy and gives the full-blown vector results.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in your observation about proving boundedness without applying linear functionals. In fact, you can take a direct approach using only vector arguments to prove the existence and value of the radius of convergence of a vector power series:

> **Theorem (Radius of Convergence):** Suppose $X$ is a complex Banach space and consider
>   $$
>       F(\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^{n}x_{n},\;\;\; \{ x_{n}\} \subset X,\;\;\lambda\in\mathbb{C}.
> $$
>   Then $F$ converges absolutely (and thus converges in $X$) for all $\lambda$ for which $\limsup_{n}|\lambda|\|x_{n}\|^{1/n} < 1$, and does not converge for any $\lambda$ for which $\limsup_{n}|\lambda|\|x_{n}\|^{1/n} > 1$.

**Proof:** It is straightforward to show that $F$ converges absolutely if $\limsup_{n}|\lambda|\|x_{n}\|^{1/n} < 1$ because, in such a case, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that
$$
              \sup_{n \ge N}|\lambda|\|x_{n}\|^{1/n} \le r < 1,
$$
which gives
$$
                  \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}|\lambda|^{n}\|x_{n}\| < r^{N}/(1-r) < \infty.
$$
Absolute convergence implies convergence because $X$ is complete, which proves that the vector power series converges absolutely for all $\lambda$ for which $\limsup_{n}|\lambda|\|x_{n}\|^{1/n} < 1$.

On the other hand, if the $\limsup$ is greater than $1$, then there exists a subsequence $\{ n_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ of the integers for which $|\lambda|\|x_{n_{k}}\|^{1/n_{k}} \ge r > 1$ which prevents the general term of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^{n}x_{n}$ from converging to $0$ and, hence, also prevents the sum from converging. $\Box$

Once you have this result, then you can consider the Laurent series for
$$
                    f(\lambda) = (x-\lambda 1)^{-1},
$$
where $x$ is an element of a complex unital Banach algebra with unit $1$. The author shows that $f$ is holomorphic for $|\lambda| > r_{\sigma}(x)$, where $r_{\sigma}(x)$ is the spectral radius; and $f$ has the Laurent series expansion
$$
      f(\lambda) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}x^{n},\;\;\;\; |\lambda| > r_{\sigma}(x),
$$
and the series cannot converge absolutely for any $\lambda_{0}$ such that $|\lambda_{0}| < r_{\sigma}(x)$ because, if it does, then it is easily verified that the series must converge to $y$ such that $y(x-\lambda 1)=(x-\lambda 1)y = 1$ for all $\lambda$ for which $|\lambda| \ge |\lambda_{0}|$. Hence,
$$
         r_{\sigma}(x) = \limsup_{n}\|x^{n}\|^{1/n}.
$$

Comment: Surely, convergence of the series holds precisely when Hadamard holds. However, that is not enough as one wants to prove that Hadamard and the spectral radius coincide and for that one must reduce to the well known complex analysis case...

Comment: @Freeze_S : You may have missed my argument: The author shows that $f$ converges absolutely for $|\lambda| > r_{\sigma}(x)$, and I showed that it cannot converge absolutely for any $\lambda_{0}$ such that $|\lambda_{0}| < r_{\sigma}(x)$. So you know the dividing line for absolute convergence is $r_{\sigma}(x)$. But, from the Theorem I proved, that dividing line is known to be $\limsup$.

Comment: Yep I got that, but if I didn't get you wrong you did prove precisely the Banach version of Hadamard, so according to the assertion stated in blockquotes you did prove that the series precisely converges for $\lambda<r_H(A)$ and diverges for $\lambda>r_H(A)$ with $r_H(A):=\limsup\|A^k\|^\frac{1}{k}$. So we certainly have $r_\sigma(A)\leq r_H(A)$ with $r_\sigma(A):=\sup\|\sigma(A)\|$. But that is not sufficient as it might be still $r_\sigma(A)<r_H(A)$.

Comment: @Freeze_S : I've shown you that the series converges for $|\lambda| > r_{H}(A)$ and diverges for $|\lambda| < r_{H}(A)$. The author shows the series converges for $|\lambda| > r_{\sigma}(A)$. I finished by showing that it cannot converge absolutely for $|\lambda| < r_{\sigma}(A)$, which means it cannot converge for any $|\lambda| < r_{\sigma}(A)$. The dividing lines must be the same, which is $r_{\sigma}(x)=\limsup_{n}\|x^{n}\|^{1/n}$.

Comment: @Freeze_S : Maybe you're not seeing how the theorem I proved shows that following: If $G(\lambda)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\lambda^{-n}x_{n}$ converges absolutely for $|\lambda| > r$ and does not converge absolutely for any $|\lambda| < r$, then $r=\limsup_{n}\|x_{n}\|^{1/n}$.

Comment: But that is precisely the punch line one has to prove that when $\lambda>r_\sigma(A)$ then it has the Laurent series expansion $f(\lambda)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{k+1}}{\lambda^k}$. The author does that using bounded linear functionals - that was kind of the OP question. Then saying well the author proves it is not very satisfactory... (Sorry if it might sound rude - it is not meant in a bad way - just discussing :))

Comment: @Freeze_S : Nope, that wasn't the OP question.

Comment: "Why does he use bounded linear functionals of $\mathcal{A}$ to show that the sequence $\{\frac{x^n}{\lambda^{n+1}}\}$ is bounded?" That is OP's question. Answer: In order to prove existence of Laurent expansion!

Comment: @Freeze_S : OP noted that the series was known to converge in the desired region. I used that fact.

Comment: OP didn't note but thinks ;)

Comment: @Freeze_S : I don't own the book, and I can only go by what the OP stated. He said the series converged, and asked if that was enough to establish boundedness. It is enough. So I stated that the assumption holds, and proved the desired result based on that assumption that the series does converge in the desired disk, without invoking linear functionals. All such results can be so proved without invoking functionals; so I assumed the author had established such convergence. Otherwise, why would OP ask this?

Comment: Because he maybe just had an idea how to prove the theorem but missed the point that convergence is not established yet...

Comment: @Freeze_S : I assumed he knew what was stated: that the series converged for $|\lambda| > r_{\sigma}(\lambda)$. You assume that he didn't know that. I stated this fact as known and worked from there. My argument is correct based on the assumptions that I stated in the solution, whether or not you like my assumptions.

Comment: Ultimatively, taking convergence as an assumption as the OP stated one doesn't need heavy machinary as Hadamard at all if one is just tempted to prove the OP's question namely wether the sequence is bounded as already shown by the OP himself!

Comment: @Freeze_S : Read the first line of my solution. Your observation is indeed trivial. I was following through with more that wasn't required to answer the question.

Comment: @Freeze_S : Here's a fun exercise: If $B$ is a Banach algebra with or without a unit, show that $\lim_{n}\|x^{n}\|^{1/n}$ exists without appealing to anything related to spectrum. Power series arguments give this directly. Sometimes its helpful to think about things in different ways. That's all I was trying to illustrate.

Comment: The question why bounded linear functionals are **needed** is still open here... Moreover it might give the OP the wrong impression that they're not needed at all. ...that is a simple exercise using the condition $a_{n+n'}\leq a_na_{n'}$ for the positive numbers $a_n:=\|A^n\|$ ;)

Comment: @Freeze_S : There are two BIG places where weak is used: (1) Proving that weak analyticity implies strong ... that's huge, especially for applications and the actual verification. (2) The Cauchy integral representation and Cauchy's Theorem extend trivially using weak and there's no other reasonable way: Just form the integrals and apply functionals. After that bootstrapping, most everything can be done using vector functions, vector integrals and vector series.

Comment: @Freeze_S : By the way, for operator functions $B(\lambda)$, weak is even more powerful because you instead verify that $x^{\star}(B(\lambda)x)$ is analytic for all $x^{\star}$ and $x$. Talk about saving effort in applications! That's part of the Complex Analysis Mathemagic. Then, on top of that, you can just prove continuity and then show that closed path integrals are zero over a region--again, great for appliications (Morera's Theorem.)

Comment: But that is not mentioned in your answer and so still the OP might get the impression everything can be proved directly by vector calculus without reducing to complex analysis at all - even your first sentence if not read correct leads the OP on a wrong way... Or do you think the OP will read all of our comments up to your important last one?!?!

Comment: Dear T.A.E. Thanks for your attention.