# Spectral radius problem

Tags: functional-analysis

Can somebody give me the proof of $r(x)= \lim \|x^n\|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ where $n\to \infty$ and $x$ belongs in an algebra? 
I am stuck and I would appreciate any help!!
Thank you

Comment: What definition do you have for the spectral radius?

Comment: There are a lot of proofs out there of this formula.  Maybe you can share the one you were reading and where you got stuck?

Comment: Duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/957606/spectral-radius-of-an-element-in-a-c-algebra.

Comment: Common references are Rudin and Murphy. I only know proofs which use complex analysis, however I also woud be interested if there is a proof which does not use this.

Comment: Thank you Martin-Blas, I will study this proof and compare the two proofs. That was helpful!

Comment: The definition is  $r(x)=\sup\{|\lambda|: \lambda\in\sigma(x)\}.$ Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a Banach algebra with unit $e$ and let $x\in\mathcal{B}$. The function $\mu \mapsto (e -\mu x)^{-1}$ is a vector function that is holomorphic in an open region $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ containing the origin. The power series for this function is
$$
        (e-\mu x)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^{n}}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n}}{d\lambda^{n}}(e-\lambda x)^{-1}\right|_{\lambda=0}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}x^{n}.
$$
The power series for the holomorphic vector function $\mu\mapsto (e-\mu x)^{-1}$ must converges for all $\mu \in B_{R}(0)$, where $B_{R}(0)$ is the largest open ball contained in $\{ \mu : (e-\mu x) \mbox{ is invertible } \}$. Therefore,
$$
     (\lambda e - x)^{-1}=\lambda^{-1}(e-\lambda^{-1}x)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}x^{n},\;\;\; |\lambda | > r_{\sigma}(x).
$$
The above cannot converge for any $\mu$ for which $|\mu| < r_{\sigma}(x)$ because it can be verified that if the above converges conditionally or absolutely for $\lambda=\mu$, then
$$
      (\lambda e-x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}x^{n} = e
   = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}x^{n}\right)(\lambda e-x),
          \;\;\; |\mu| < |\lambda|,
$$
which would contradict the definition of spectral radius. But it is also known  that the series converges absolutely for
$$
           \limsup_{n} \|x^{n}\|^{1/n} < |\lambda|.
$$
and diverges for
$$
             \limsup_{n} \|x^{n}\|^{1/n} > |\lambda|
$$
Therefore
$$
           r_{\sigma}(x) = 1/\limsup_{n}\|x^{n}\|^{1/n}
$$
If $\|x^{k}\|^{1/k} < |\lambda|$ for some positive integer $k$ then the following converges absolutely:
$$
     \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n}}x^{n}
   = \frac{1}{\lambda}\left\{e+\frac{1}{\lambda}x+\cdots+\frac{1}{\lambda^{k-1}}x^{k-1}\right\}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{kn}}x^{kn}.
$$
Hence, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda^{n+1}}x^{n}$ converges absolutely if $\inf_{k > 0}\|x^{k}\|^{1/k} < |\lambda|$. Hence,
$$
              \limsup_{k}\|x^{k}\|^{1/k} \le \inf_{k > 0}\|x^{k}\|^{1/k}
       \le \liminf_{k}\|x^{k}\|^{1/k}
$$
Therefore $\lim_{k}\|x^{k}\|^{1/k}$ exists and
$$
            r_{\sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{\lim_{k}\|x^{k}\|^{1/k}}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!! It is very helpful!